# Simplified Helmholtz decomposition

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose we are given a vector field
$$\vec{a}= (x+y+z)\vec{i}+y\vec{j}+z\vec{k}  \tag{$*$}$$
And we want to write it as a linear combination of a potential field and a solenoidal field, meaning $$\vec{a}= \vec{p}+\vec{s}$$
where $$\vec{p}= \nabla\phi $$
with  $\phi$ being the potential of the corresponding potential field.
I first applied the divergence operator to both sides of eqn $\left (* \right )$
and got $$\operatorname{div}\vec{a}= \operatorname{div}(\operatorname{grad}(\phi))=3$$
Now my goal is to find the potential function. I've read in  a paper, that to do so, you just have to perform antiderivation twice on $\operatorname{div} (\operatorname{grad}(b))$. Doing so I got that $$\phi = \frac{3}{2}x^2+C$$
However, what's bugging me is the fact that $\operatorname{div} (\operatorname{grad}(\phi))= \Delta b$ which is the Laplacian, and it involves not only the partial derivatives with respect to $x$. What happened here to the other two variables? Is this approach valid?

Comment: When antidifferentiating with respect to $x$, the resulting $C$ is a constant _with respect to $x$_, i.e. it should properly be $C(x,y)$. If you then take the Laplacian, you'll get $\partial_{yy}C+\partial_{zz}C=3$. From here you can now antidifferentiate twice to get a function of $z$ alone. If you repeat that once more, what do you have?

Comment: A function of $y$ alone? Feel free to post an answer.